# StreamFieldPanel too small

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

Is there a way to stop the admin panels from getting so small? I have elements nested 3 layers deep, and that 3rd layer is just so narrow. I understand the indentation on the left, but there is so much wasted space on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something the Wagtail team is working on improving (https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3942) - for now, there are a number of third-party addons (including [Wagtail Atomic Admin](https://github.com/alexgleason/wagtailatomicadmin) and [wagtailclearstream](https://github.com/heymonkeyriot/wagtailclearstream)) aimed at improving the StreamField editor UI.

However, I'd urge you to consider whether giving your content editors such low-level control over layout is really a good thing. If you build a StreamField out of generic all-purpose blocks containing other all-purpose blocks - rather than ones with a well-defined meaning in the context of your site ("call to action", "testimonial" or whatever...) then all you're really doing is reinventing the `<div>` tag with an interface that's more cumbersome than hand-writing HTML.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the add-ons. That should help.

I agree about the rest, but that's just not possible for what's being asked.